# Dynamic URL in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having trouble to dynamic the url using codeigniter.
I need to display dynamic URL look like below.
http://example.com/[store-url]

I did that. But when i try to view non-dynamic url like
http://example.com/blog. It accesssing store page only.

So i have wrote in my routes like below and it is working.
$route['blog'] = "blog";

But here my problem is i am having lot pages such as /blog. all pages are pointing the stores pages only including admin control panel

There any solution for that without setting the routes

Comment: I don't really see an alternative without setting a route. What about `http://example.com/store/[store-url]`?

Answer (score 0):

In the routes.php

First wirte the coding of Dynamic URL

like

```
include_once (APPPATH . 'helpers/inflector_helper.php');

$path = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'www.expample.com') {
    $controller = $path[1];
} else {
   $controller = $path[2];
}

$route[$controller] = plural($controller) . "/view" . ucwords($controller);
$route[$controller . '/list'] = plural($controller) . "/view" . ucwords($controller);
$route[$controller . '/view/(:num)'] = plural($controller) . "/view" . ucwords($controller) . "/$1";
$route[$controller . '/view/(:num)/(:any)'] = plural($controller) . "/view" . ucwords($controller) . "/$1/$2";
```

I write my static url

```
$route['login'] = "authenticate_user/index";
$route['validate'] = "authenticate_user/validateUser";
$route['logout'] = "authenticate_user/logout";
```

I hope this should work.